# MySQL MATCH AGAINST returns rows that don't match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a `MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE` but it is returning rows that don't have any occurrence of "Nathan" in any of the `MATCH()`'d columns. Here is my current query format:

```
SELECT `some_rows` 
LEFT JOIN `t1` ON `stuff`
LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `stuff`
LEFT JOIN `t3` ON `stuff`
WHERE MATCH(`some_rows`) AGAINST("Nathan" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

All three tables use `MyISAM` with a `DYNAMIC` row format and all of the collations of the tables and rows are the same.

Can somebody shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241739/204263). My problem (assumably) was that I was trying to `MATCH()` columns from multiple tables which apparently you are not allowed to do. I corrected my query to something like this:

```
SELECT `some_rows` 
LEFT JOIN `t1` ON `stuff`
LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `stuff`
LEFT JOIN `t3` ON `stuff`
WHERE 
MATCH(`t1`.`some_rows`) AGAINST("Nathan" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(`t2`.`some_rows`) AGAINST("Nathan" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(`t3`.`some_rows`) AGAINST("Nathan" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I hope this helps somebody.