# Create valid MySQL query with two LEFT JOINs, MATCH AGAINST and FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, full-text-indexing, match-against

I am trying to create a SELECT query that combines 3 tables via `LEFT JOIN` and then `MATCH` specific keywords `AGAINST` the resulting table.

My testing so far reveals that the query is working fine and the output results are correct, however I have a doubt about FULLTEXT indexes when joining tables via `LEFT JOIN`.

The question is - should I add additional code to reflect the `FULLTEXT` index requirement for `MATCH AGAINST` when doing `LEFT JOIN` or only correct indexing of the relevant columns in the original tables is enough?

Reason for asking is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241602/mysql-match-across-multiple-tables). If I understand it correct my code should not work (since "You can't define fulltext indexes...across multiple tables in MySQL"). Therefore `MATCH AGAINST` for `ma.name_url` and `v.model`, would not work as they are not indexed (or this how I understand it, correct me if I am wrong :) ).

However, as the query output seems to be correct I need an expert advice if the below code is correct or I should add/modify something:

```
SELECT v.*, vt.color, ma.* 
          FROM tbl_items AS v 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_options
            AS vt on v.id = vt.v_id 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_names
            AS ma on v.make = ma.id 
         WHERE 
               ( 
                      ( 
                  MATCH (ma.name_url) AGAINST ('keyword1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
               OR MATCH (v.model) AGAINST ('keyword1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                      ) 
           AND 
                      ( 
                  MATCH (ma.name_url) AGAINST ('keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
               OR MATCH (v.model) AGAINST ('keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                      ) 
               ) 
           AND v.type = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misreading the post.  A *single* full text index only refers to one table.  Actually, this is true for all other indexes, so I'm not sure why there is confusion.  The index *can* refer to multiple columns within the table, but only to one table.

As for your query, I'm not sure which is more important -- the full text indexes or the regular indexes.

As your query is written, you are returning `ma` rows that do not match the `match` condition.  Perhaps this is fine, but it looks suspicious.

And, if performance is an issue, you might find that breaking the query into separate subqueries (connected by `UNION` or `UNION ALL`) gives better performance.  Each subquery can be optimized more efficiently.

Comment: So the fact that I have correctly defined Indexes and Full text indexes in the columns used in `MATCH AGAINST` is fine? What if I don't have `FULLTEXT` index on `name_url` in `tbl_names` for example? It seems that this does not affect the output? Also, yes first I am joining all `ma` rows and then I perform a `MATCH` to find which of those rows fit the condition.

Comment: @user3132858 . . . A boolean search does not require a FULLTEXT, although it is much slower.  My point is that all the filtering may be on `v` and not on `ma`, so you will have `ma` rows were none of them match the conditions.

Comment: thank you for the desire to help out...so basically you are saying that if I have a keyword that only matches an `ma` row, that row will not be in the query result? I tried that, search for only 1 keyword contained in just one row in `ma` and the result is as expected...

Comment: @user3132858 . . . No, I'm saying the opposite.  If you have keywords that only match on `v`, you are going to get all the corresponding `ma` rows and they don't have the keywords.