# How to create a full in-site search with PHP for all my tables?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I need to search all content of my site in all modules and pages with PHP. i have no static page and all of my site is in MySQL. All samples in the web just explain how to search in one MySQL table. But I need to search all my tables except administration tables. I think it is not fair If I to join all of them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I think this question is unfortunately not going to be received well on Stack Overflow because you haven't presented any specific code you need help with. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I answered a related question a long time ago, and the answer is still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241602/mysql-match-across-multiple-tables/1241739#1241739 I think the solution you want is to use ElasticSearch, and denormalize your data as you copy it from each of your MySQL tables into an ElasticSearch index.